# Flex4: Combo Box with CheckBox Inside

Tags: apache-flex, checkbox, data-binding, combobox, flex4

Apologies for all the simple questions but they are born of my sudden and unplanned migration from flex 3 to flex 4.

Ok I have a combo box which I would like to show a list of selectable check boxes.

```
<s:ComboBox   x="181" y="-7" width="233" id="dropISLIST" itemRenderer="IsListFilterCheckBox" dataProvider="{GetIsList.lastResult.ReportFilterList.ReportFilter}" color="#000000"/>
```

To this end I have built the following item renderer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                autoDrawBackground="true" width="142" height="22">
    <s:CheckBox x="0" y="2" label="{data}" color="#000000"/>

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Now that all works fine, how ever, I can not "Check" a box, what I would like to be able to do is have the user be able to select a number of check boxes. And then also figure out what they have checked.

Any help in this regard would be greatly apreciated thank you so much in advance.

Regards
Craig

Comment: I found this http://www.blastanova.com/blog/2010/06/23/a-custom-multi-selection-spark-dropdownlist/ but I cant seem to figure out how to address the component to return the combobox.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: I did I used a component to give me an isEqual list style fix ComboCheck.swc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this component.  It should do everything you are needing
http://www.carballares.es/en/arcadio/?page_id=352